# Booked a ticket but never got charged for it

Tags: tickets, airlines

I booked a Turkish Airlines ticket through a 3rd party website (Indian Eagle) that I got a confirmation from. I have the ticket number and the confirmation number for the same. Both the airline and the 3rd party merchant have confirmed that this has been processed and my ticket is valid. However, I do not see a transaction posted in my credit card for this and when I asked my bank, even they do not see any such transaction. I distinctly remember this transaction coming up as Pending on my account but it never got posted. It has been over a month since I purchased this ticket but no trace of a transaction being posted.

What do I do here? Will my ticket be cancelled at the last minute?

Comment: Usually transactions are cleared within a few days up to a week or so, but there's no limit to this per se. It's possible some internal issue prevented the charge from being processed correctly. In this case, it'll probably come up when somebody looks through transaction at the end of the month or so, and they may be repeating the charge manually then. So you may see the charge in a few weeks time. It's impossible to tell what exactly the airline may or may not do. *You* don't appear to be at fault with anything, so it's unlikely they'll cancel the ticket; but again, impossible to say.

Comment: If you're incredibly lucky, it may slip through the cracks due to technical issues/ineptitude, and you'll never get charged for it. But I wouldn't be holding my breath for that; if Indian Eagle lets charges slip through regularly, they won't be in business for long.

Comment: @deceze Generally, the airline charges the card. The travel agent/booking service merely passes along the number.

Comment: Yup, all of these are helpful. Thank you! @deceze